# Xcode8 upgrade make a view size not load from auto layout in awakeFromNib method

Tags: objective-c, xcode8

I have a MyView in storyboard that have a auto layout , when the awakeFromNib in the MyView m.class

int this methods  self.frame is (0,0,1000,1000)

```
 -(void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    [self addStar];
}
```

-(void)addStar
     {

```
    starView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:self.frame];
    [self addSubview:starView];

 }
```

but if I change to addStar with delay the self.frame is (0,0,25,75)

```
[self performSelector:@selector(addStar) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
```

this problem show after Xcode 8 upgrade, please help me (-:

Answer (score 0):

Resaving your document in Xcode 8.1 beta 2 and higher will restore explicit frames, which should avoid the 1000x1000 at runtime.

You can also set the autoresizing mask to flexible width and height, which should work in Xcode 8.

A final option is to set the frame of `starView` in `-layoutSubviews`, but this is not ideal.